# Como passar uma lista do componente filho para o componente pai com vue e blade php

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

Estou com um problema,preciso acessar a lista que crio no componente `selectprodutos` e persistir ela,porém o envio é feito de outro *component* chamado `formulario`. Os mesmos se dispõem na seguinte ordem:

> blade>modal>formulario>selectprodutos.

Então eu persistiria a lista criada pelo componente filho `selectprodutos` pelo componente pai `formulario`. Segue o trecho do código que tentei:

Blade:

```
 @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
        <pagina tamanho="12">
            @if($errors->all())

                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    @foreach($errors->all() as $key => $value)
                        <p>{{$value}}</p>
                    @endforeach
                </div>

            @endif
            <painel titulo="Lista de O.S.">


                <tabela-lista
                    :titulos="['#','Nome','Registro','Vendedor','Operador','Data','Pragas','Produtos']"
                    itens=""
                    criar="#criar"
                    editar="/admin/os/"
                    deletar="/admin/os/"
                    token="{{csrf_token()}}"
                    ordem="desc"
                    ordemcol="0"
                    modal="sim">
                </tabela-lista>
                <div align="center">
    {{--                {{$lista}}--}}
                </div>
            </painel>
        </pagina>

        <!-- MODAL ADD -->
        <modal nome="adicionar" titulo="Adicionar">
            <formulario id="formAdicionar" css="" action="{{route('operador.store')}}" method="post"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data" token="{{csrf_token()}}">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome do Operador" value="{{old('nome')}}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="unmedida">Operadores</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="operador" id="operador">
                        @foreach($operadores as $key => $operador )
                            <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $operador }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="unmedida">Produtos</label>
                    <selectprodutos @mutableList="printMutableList" id="produtos" nome="produtos" :lista="{{$produtos}}"></selectprodutos>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="unmedida">Unidade de medida</label>
                    <input type="number" min="1" max="4" class="form-control" id="nivel" name="nivel" placeholder="Nivel de 1 a 4"
                           enctype="multipart/form-data" value="{{old('nivel')}}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="registro">Registro NEOS</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registro" name="registro" placeholder="Registro no NEOS"
                           enctype="multipart/form-data" value="{{old('registro')}}">
                </div>


            </formulario>
            <span slot="botoes"><button form="formAdicionar" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button></span>

        </modal>

        <!-- MODAL EDIT -->
        <modal nome="editar" titulo="Editar">
            <formulario id="formEditar" css="" :action="'/admin/operador/' + $store.state.item.id" method="put" enctype="multipart/form-data" token="{{csrf_token()}}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" v-model="$store.state.item.nome" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome do produto" >
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="unmedida">Nivel</label>
                    <input type="number" min="1" max="4" class="form-control"  :value="$store.state.item.nivel" id="nivel" name="nivel" placeholder="Nivel de 1 a 4"
                           enctype="multipart/form-data">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="registro">Registro NEOS</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="registro" v-model="$store.state.item.registro" name="registro" placeholder="Registro no NEOS"
                           enctype="multipart/form-data">
                </div>



            </formulario>
            <span slot="botoes"> <button form="formEditar" class="btn btn-info">Adicionar</button></span>
        </modal>

        {{--<!-- MODAL DETAIL -->--}}
        {{--<modal nome="detalhe" v-bind:titulo="$store.state.item.titulo">--}}


        {{--    <p>@{{$store.state.item.descricao}}</p>--}}
        {{--    <br>--}}
        {{--    <p>@{{$store.state.item.conteudo}}</p>--}}


        {{--</modal>--}}
    @endsection
    {{--<style>--}}
    {{--    .img {--}}
    {{--        width: 100% !important;--}}
    {{--    }--}}
    {{--</style>--}}
    <script>
        import Selectproduto from "../../../js/components/SelectProdutos";
        export default {
            components: {Selectproduto}
        }
    </script>
```

no componente `selectprodutos` coloquei um emit no metodo add:

```
 <template>
<div>
    <select class="form-control" name="nomeselect" id="idselect">
        <option v-for="(value, key) in lista"
                :value="key"
                :key="key">
            {{value}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button type="button" v-on:click="addprd()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> + </button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table v-if="this.mutableList != undefined" class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"> Remover </th>
            <th scope="col"> # </th>
            <th scope="col">Produto</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(item,index) in this.mutableList" :key="index">
            <td><button type="button" v-on:click="rmprd(index)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"> x </button></td>
            <td v-for="i in item" :key="i">{{i}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>


</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "selectproduto",
        props:[
            "nome",
            "lista",
            "id",
            "selecionados"
        ],
        data:function(){
            return {
                mutableList: this.selecionados
        }
        },
        mounted() {
            // console.log('oia a ');
        },
        methods: {
            addprd: function() {
                var e = document.getElementById("idselect");
                var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
                if (this.mutableList == undefined) {
                    this.mutableList = new Array();
                }
                this.mutableList.push(new Array(value,text));
                console.log(this.mutableList);
                this.$emit("setParentComponentDetails");
            },
            rmprd: function(index) {
                this.mutableList.splice(index);
                if (this.mutableList.length <= 0){
                    this.mutableList = undefined;
                }
                console.log(this.mutableList);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

No componente de `formulario` coloquei um método para dar *log* só pra ver se estava funcionando o evento:

```
<template>
      <form v-bind:class="css" v-bind:action="action" v-bind:method="defineMethod" v-bind:enctype="enctype">
        <input v-if="token" type="hidden" name="_token" v-bind:value="token">
        <input v-if="alterMethod" type="hidden" name="_method" v-bind:value="alterMethod">
        <slot></slot>
      </form>
    </template>

    <script>
        import SelectProdutos from './SelectProdutos.vue';
        export default {
            component:{
                SelectProdutos
            },
            props:['css','action','method','enctype','token'],
            data:function(){
                return{
                    alterMethod:""
                }
            },
            computed:{
                defineMethod:function(){
                    if(this.method.toLowerCase() == "post" || this.method.toLowerCase() == "get"){
                        return this.method.toLowerCase();
                    }
                    if(this.method.toLowerCase() == "put"){
                        this.alterMethod="put";
                    }
                    if(this.method.toLowerCase() == "delete"){
                        this.alterMethod="delete";
                    }
                    return "post";

                }
            },
            methods:{
                printMutableList(){
                    console.log('Deu certo');
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Mas ele da o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se colocar duas vez methods:{) o segundo vai substituir o primeiro, separe os métodos

methods:{
printMutableList()
    {
    ...
    },
    addprd: function() {
    ...
    }

}

Comment: esse ultimo é no componente de formulário,o primeiro no componente selectprodutos

Comment: Coloque o código completo

Comment: coloquei da blade e dos dois componentes agora

Comment: <selectprodutos @mutableList="printMutableList" , o printMutableList apenas existe dentro do componente <selectprodutos> e não pode ser invocado fora

Comment: qual método eu uso para recuperar a informação de dentro do componente então?minha ideia era usar esse @mutableList="printMutableList" para capturar a lista de dentro do componente atraves do emit

Comment: No seu componente deve gerar um evento (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) quando a lista alterar ex. this.$emit('listchanged') , depois no seu componente exterior @listchanged="nome_do_metodo_a_executar"